# Simply Playing A Sound in iOS

Tags: ios, audiotoolbox

I'm trying to play a sound when a button is clicked. First, I imported the AudioToolbox in the header file, then added the code into the IBAction that fires when the button is pressed, like so:

```
    - (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];
}
- (IBAction)button1:(id)sender {
    NSString *soundPath = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"mySong" ofType:@"wav"];
     SystemSoundID soundID;
     AudioServicesCreateSystemSoundID((__bridge CFURLRef)[NSURL fileURLWithPath:soundPath], &soundID);
    AudioServicesPlaySystemSound (soundID);
}
```

I even threw an NSLog in the method to make sure it's firing. It is. I also but in a foo path in the string to see if it would crash, it did. I made sure that I dragged and dropped the short sound file into the app as well. Tested my speakers, tested audio on the device simulator by going to youtube on the simulator, everything. I can't figure out what I'm doing wrong.

When I changed the code to this:

```
- (IBAction)button1:(id)sender {


    AVAudioPlayer *testAudioPlayer;

    // *** Implementation... ***

    // Load the audio data
    NSString *soundFilePath = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"3" ofType:@"wav"];
    NSData *sampleData = [[NSData alloc] initWithContentsOfFile:soundFilePath];
    NSError *audioError = nil;

    // Set up the audio player
    testAudioPlayer = [[AVAudioPlayer alloc] initWithData:sampleData error:&audioError];


    if(audioError != nil) {
        NSLog(@"An audio error occurred: \"%@\"", audioError);
    }
    else {
        [testAudioPlayer setNumberOfLoops: -1];
        [testAudioPlayer play];
    }}
```

I get the error: WARNING:   137: Error '!dat' trying to set the (null) audio devices' sample rate

Comment: Try testing on a device rather than in the simulator.

Answer (score 1):

Hi as per you question can you please check whether you audio file is present in you project folder.It might happen that u have forgotten to checkmark "copy item if needed" so it might not be there in your project file.

You can also play sounds provided in device. Visit the below link it will be helpful.

https://github.com/TUNER88/iOSSystemSoundsLibrary

I've tested your code and it working fine and not getting crashed. Here's what I did.
[image]

Comment: Yes, it is present in my project file.

Comment: You can also try the demo from the link it might solve your problem. I've added the image of what i did and it's giving me proper path and not getting crash.

Answer (score 1):

As said in @matt's comment, sound playback fails in the Simulator. I had this problem when trying to play back a video.

The funny part is that sound plays just fine for the same video inside the Photos app.